# How to generate AWS CLI equivalent of any console operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cloudshell

How can I find the CLI equivalent of any console operation in AWS?

Is there any way to generate that?

Comment: I wish the AWS Console has the Google Cloud console "equivalent gcloud CLI commands".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some services AWS provides such equivalent, but there is no general way for that. You could try a third party tool [Console Recorder for AWS](https://github.com/iann0036/AWSConsoleRecorder):

> Records actions made in the AWS Management Console and **outputs the equivalent CLI/SDK commands** and CloudFormation/Terraform templates.